# Can't get Highcharts to work in rails. Is jquery.min the issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I downloaded Highcharts and unzipped the folder. I didn't place the unzipped folder in my rails app however, I simply copy and pasted the `highcharts.js` to my `vendor/assets/javascript` folder.

Next, to make sure it was working I copy and pasted the sample chart in the documentation into a view. Therefore I don't expect my code to be incorrect. However the view only shows a blank page now.

I tried googling but I can't figure out the issue. I think it might have something to do with jquery.min but I'm not entirely sure. It seems jquery.min is messing up my other jquery functions so that's why I think it might be that...I am using jquery from the jquery-rails 2.0.2 gem.

My View:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"%>
<%= javascript_include_tag "highcharts" %>

<script>
$(function () { 
$('#chart').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit eaten'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4]
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 7, 3]
    }]
});
});​
</script>

<div id = "chart"> </div>
```

And my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.numeric
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap
```

Comment: Why do you include `jQuery` from the gem in your `application.js` and  then `jQuery` from Google's CDN in your view?

Comment: @TimPetricola I was just copying the code from the high charts docs page http://docs.highcharts.com/#installation. However I've tried removing that javascript tag to no avail.

Comment: Yeah if you already include it in your application.js, you don't need it a second time :) but it's probably not the issue here. Do you have any error in the developer tools' console?

Comment: @TimPetricola I have one `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` which highlights the semicolon at the end of the function before the script ends. It doesn't seem to make sense. I think I am including jquery in my application.js but the program needs jquery.min to work? Would that make sense?

Comment: @TimPetricola actually I just deleted the last line and rewrote it. That error is gone. Still no chart popping up though

Comment: Such a weird place to be putting anything in your vendor/assets. You should have something like this in your `application.js` - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5235096 You clearly are not doing `require highchars` which is why it will not pop up.

Comment: `jquery.min.js` is the same as `jquery.js` except that all whitespaces have been removed to have a smaller file.

Comment: @Chowza try removing jquery.min.js. Do you have `highcharts.js` in your `assets/javascript` ?

Comment: @David I think you wanted to adress this comment to Chowza :)

Comment: @TimPetricola Ok...I got it to work in a non-acceptable way...It should lead to the answer but I still need help with it. If I remove `//=require jquery` and I include Google's jquery.min in my view it works. So I guess my question is, how do I get it to work with `require jquery`? The reason I need require jquery is because I have a lot of functions which need jquery, in addition to bootstrap, etc

Comment: @David I did try removing `jquery.min` but it didn't do anything. I do have `highcharts.js` in my `vendor/assets/javascripts`. I know it is being located by the rails app. Regarding your original suggestion, I don't have exporting or highcharts/highcharts-more. I don't know what those are?

Comment: @Chowza `exporting` is just an additional javascript file that enables you to export your highchart to different formats. What version of rails are you using?

Comment: @David I am using Rails 3.2. @TimPetricola I am such a noob. The reason I was having a problem was because I had `//=require jquery` but didn't have `<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery" %>` in my view. I'm not sure why I have to include that as it doesn't need to in any of my other views, but this fixed my problem. Thanks everyone!

Comment: That still isn't working for me -- I'm having the same problem (except with Rails 4). Does anybody have a minimal working rails + highcharts app they could post somewhere, so I can compare and contrast with what I have?